# Apple 5S Charge-Only USB Mode

Tags: iphone, usb, security

Is there any way to make the phone content inaccessible when connected via USB to PC. I want to do some settings on iphone itself so that the Internal storage isn't visible on laptop/PC to which it's connected.

I want to use USB only for charging.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no there is no way to set a default option of how your iPhone interacts with a computer. However if you plug in your iPhone it will ask you if you trust this computer and you click no, then that computer will not be able to see any data on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Data blocked" and charge only adapter or USB cable. Typically it is like you are charging from wall mount usb adapter.